# gnu gcc asm; using "C" enum values

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, enums, header-files

Is there a way to extract a value from "C" `enum` to pass them into gnu gcc asm ('.S' file) w/o some sort of external parser?

What I want to get is

"my_header.h"

```
enum myErrors
{
    NoError = 0,
    TimeOut = 1,
    BadArgument = 30,
};
```

"asm_file.S"

```
mov r0, #myErrors.TimeOut
```

PS: For now the only solution I see is to parse "my_header.h" and create an auxiliary file with a bunch of `#define` to be included into "asm_file.S".
Maybe there is a nice solution for this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a semicolon missing after your enum definition.

Comment: Why are you working in assembly in the first place? The only plausible reason I can think off is to manually optimize some speed critical section. In that case the assembly should just perform the speed-critical job and leave the error handling to the C code. That removes the need to get access to your enum from asm.

Comment: @Unimportant, because it's exactly "speed critical section" and it could fail and has to return error

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the header files, you could write some macros so that when included in C code it spits out the `enum`, and when in asm, a bunch of `.equ`.

Example:

```
#ifdef ASM
#define ENUM(x) .macro item name value ; .equ x##.\name, \value ; .endm
#define ITEM(x, y) item x, y
#define END_ENUM .purgem item
#else 
#define ENUM(x) enum x {
#define ITEM(x, y) x = y,
#define END_ENUM }
#endif

ENUM(myErrors)
ITEM(NoError, 0)
ITEM(TimeOut, 1)
ITEM(BadArgument, 30)
END_ENUM
```

Obviously you need preprocessed assembly for this (e.g. `.S` file and `gcc` driver). Also, your build system will need to define `ASM` (or find an appropriate predefined macro to detect language).

Comment: Sorry this is not acceptable. I'd not be allowed to push such 'enum' ugliness.

Comment: I like your answer, as it shows there is a way to generate the enum in such a way that it is useful in both assembler and _C_.(assuming the _C_ pre-processor if available). The OP put no constraints except that it isn't an external parser. Seems to me this fits the bill.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you can do this:

```
enum myErrors
{
    NoError = 0,
    TimeOut = 1,
    BadArgument = 30
};

constexpr myErrors no_error = NoError,
                   time_out = TimeOut,
                   bad_argument = BadArgument;

static myErrors last_error = no_error;

myErrors get_last_error()
{
  return last_error;
}
```

Compiled with g++ 6.2.0 on Linux x86_64, and no optimization flags, this produces the following assembly:

```
_Z14get_last_errorv:
.LFB0:
    .file 1 "sx-myerror.cpp"
    .loc 1 15 0
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    .loc 1 16 0
    movl    _ZL10last_error(%rip), %eax
    .loc 1 17 0
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

The line `movl  _ZL10last_error(%rip), %eax` is close to what you wanted.  If you optimize, it replaces that symbolic constant with a literal 0.

In C, what you can do is:

```
typedef enum myErrors
{
    NoError = 0,
    TimeOut = 1,
    BadArgument = 30
} myErrors;

const myErrors no_error = NoError,
               time_out = TimeOut,
               bad_argument = BadArgument;

myErrors get_last_error()
{
  return no_error;
}
```

This is not as flexible: you cannot use the `const` objects in static initializers, and the compiler optimizes them to constants.  However, it does get you symbolic constant names in the object code.

Comment: so I should create a wrapper function for each enum-value and call appropriate function. Do I get it right?

Comment: No, the wrapper function is just a demonstration of the use of the symbolic constants.  I included it in order to verify the kind of function body `gcc -c` would produce.

Comment: alright. I think I got you. There is a bunch of constants for each enum-value. And function should read the value of constant into register before returning it. Right? It could be even a bit easier to remove name mangling: `myErrors myNoError  asm("asm_no_error") = NoError;`. Drawbacks are a lot of extra manually declared constants (I have around 50 error codes) and extra instructions in speed critical code. This means that one `mov r0, #error_code` instruction should be replaced with 3 (2 instruction to load address of constant + 1 memory reading to read a value).

Comment: The function is just a minimal example of the use of one of the constants, in this context.  I included it so there would be some instructions to show, and not just a bunch of variable declarations.